# How to write output of each HTML page into multiple files in Python?

Tags: python

I created a code that would generate each HTML page as output to save in different files by iteration of for loop.

```
import requests
import urllib.request

def crawlpages():
    for i in range(1451720, 1451730):
        link = "https://www.mmo-champion.com/members/" + str(i)
        content = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
        mydata = content.read()
        with open('Newfile.html%s' %i,'wb') as file:
            file.write(mydata)

crawlpages()
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  What doesn't work about your current code?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `requests`.

```
import requests

def crawlpages():
    for i in range(1451720, 1451730):
        link = "https://www.mmo-champion.com/members/" + str(i)
        response = requests.get(link)
        mydata = response.content
        with open('Newfile.html%s' %i,'wb') as file:
            file.write(mydata)

crawlpages()
```